# Swift : EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift

I ran into the error code that haunts any Apple developer today `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` .. After ample amounts of research, on different ways to debug etc I have landed here.

UPDATE : Here is the link to the GitHub repo if anyones willing to help solve this problem https://github.com/TheRiseCollection/sway

Turning on `zombie objects` in Xcode showed me that the `nil` here `guard let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? T` is causing my problem `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeec121e98)`

Here is a look at the full file NibView.swift

```
//Joshua Paulsen - The Rise Collection



import UIKit

/// A base UIView subclass that instaniates a view
/// from a nib file of the same class name in order to
/// allow reusable views to be created.
internal protocol NibView where Self: UIView {

}

extension NibView {

    /// Initializes the view from a xib
    /// file and configure initial constrains.
    func xibSetup() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        let view = loadViewFromNib()
        addEdgeConstrainedSubView(view: view)
    }

    /// Loads a view from it's xib file.
    ///
    /// - Returns: an instantiated view from the Nib file of the same class name.
    fileprivate func loadViewFromNib<T: UIView>() -> T {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        guard let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? T else {
            fatalError("Cannot instantiate a UIView from the nib for class \(type(of: self))")
        }
        return view
    }

}
```

I'm new to messing around with nib views! Looking for a fix here any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's actually `nil` from that statement?  It could be that nib is nil, or instantiate returns nil.  Otherwise if .first was nil or the Type Conversion changed then you'd fall through to your error handling.

Comment: @ChrisAllwein I want to say the Type Conversion changed but I am not sure why! Also a side note im new to using Generics so something may have been messed up.

But this error came along after I added a new xib view to my project.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "Type Conversion failed".  But again, in that case you'd get your "Cannot instantiate..." error and not `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.  Verify that you have the EXACT SAME Class name and Nib file name.  If you can include those, it might be helpful.

Comment: @ChrisAllwein StaticShadowHeaderView3.swift and StaticShadowHeaderView3.xib are the newly added files. both are named the same etc

Comment: Is the class name in StaticShadowHeaderView3.swift also the same?

Comment: @ChrisAllwein yes it is `class StaticShadowHeaderView3: UIView, NibView {`

Comment: Inside the xib file, if you select the main view, you can assign a class name to the view.  Has that been done and also set to StaticShadowHeaderView3?

Comment: See image in Step 6.  https://medium.com/@brianclouser/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960

Comment: @ChrisAllwein Yes that has also been done already. I appreciate the link!

Comment: @enjayem could you look at this? I have a github repo for anyone that is willing to help me find the problem

Comment: Have you tried removing the Custom Class (revert it to default UIView) from StaticShadowHeaderView3.xib ?

Comment: could you give a code example @OOPer ? just for the sake of the thread

Comment: No code update. Just remove the Custom Class setting of the xib file.

Comment: @OOPer didnt work sadly

Comment: Have you tried removing Custom Class from both StaticShadowHeaderView.xib and StaticShadowHeaderView3.xib ?

Comment: @OOPer that worked thanks!

Comment: General description, your StaticShadowHeaderViewX.xib represents a subview added to the instance of `StaticShadowHeaderViewX` class. So its class should not be `StaticShadowHeaderViewX`. If the class of the .xib is marked as `StaticShadowHeaderViewX`, it's initializer tries to instantiate itself through xib and in the initializer tries to... Infinite recursive call, stack overflows and your app crashes. _Using xib in storyboard_ is a sort of hack and you may need extra caution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having custom classes , assigned to each view I had was causing this EXC_BAD_ACCESS bug to fire off.

Removing them stopped it. Lets keep this question going with fixes to the infamous EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Thanks everyone for the help.